# xpath for locating li with text does not work

Tags: xpath, selenium-ide

Using the xpath `//ul//li[contains(text(),"outer")]` to find a li in the outer ul does not work

```
<ul>
  <li>
   <span> not unique text, </span>
   <span> not unique text, </span>
   outer ul li 1
   <ul >
     <li> inner ul li 1 </li>
     <li> inner ul li 2 </li>   
   </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
   <span> not unique text, </span>
   <span> not unique text, </span>
   outer ul li 2
   <ul >
     <li> inner ul li 1 </li>
     <li> inner ul li 2 </li>   
   </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Any idea how to find a li with a specific text in the outer ul?

Thank you

Comment: The phrase "does not work" should be a clue to you that you need to specify at least (a) what you expected to happen, and (b) what actually happened.

Comment: @LarsH, I think the question is clear for those who has knowledge about Selenium ide. And both of (a) and (b) you mentioned are in the question. Thank you for taking time to comment.

Comment: For (a), there's "to find a li in the outer ul", which is confusing since it conflicts with the apparent intent of the XPath, which is to find a `<li>` anywhere that contains the text "outer". Specifying exactly which nodes you expect the XPath to return would clear up the confusion about your intent. I don't see (b) specified at all. Maybe your XPath returns too many `<li>`s, or maybe none, or maybe the wrong ones?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This will work for you `//ul//li[contains(.,"outer")]`

Comment: Would the downvoter please comment? The answer seems correct to me.

Comment: @LarsH: This would select and test any text in any descendant of the li (also from li in deeper level or from span).

Answer (score 2):

I would expect that you only like to consider the text nodes which are direct child of the `li`. Therefore you are right with using `text()` (if you use `contains(.,"outer")` this will consider text form any children of li).

Therefore try this:

```
//ul/li[text()[contains(.,'outer')]]
```

Comment: I don't see how this would give the OP any different behavior than the XPath he already has.

Comment: @LarsH: Good question ;-). I have thought the original xpath should do. But I gave it a try with xsltproc, and it did **not**. The one above did. But I have to admit that I do not have a explanation why the original did not.

Comment: See my answer for an explanation of why the first one fails.

Comment: @MichaelKay: Ok thanks! I was just reading [xpath string](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-string): "_A node-set is converted to a string by returning the string-value of the node in the node-set that is first in document order. If the node-set is empty, an empty string is returned._"

Answer (score 2):

Running this with Saxon, the original XPath expression gives:

XPTY0004: A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the first argument of
  contains() ("", "", ...)

Now, I guess Selenium is probably using XPath 1.0 rather than XPath 2.0, and in 1.0 the contains() function has "first item semantics" - it converts its argument to a string, which if the argument is a node-set containing more than one node, involves considering only the first node. And the first text node is probably whitespace.

If you want to test whether some child text node contains "outer", use

```
//ul//li[text()[contains(.,"outer")]]
```

Another reason for switching to XPath 2.0...

Answer (score 0):

For above issue -

This solution will work

//ul//li[contains(.,"outer")]

"." Selects the current node